# Set cmd with wget and header expect

Tags: linux, expect

I have the following expect script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set SRCFILE /tmp/cert.zip
set SRC https://na.artifactory.swg-devops.com/artifactory/generic-local//latest/misc/copy_zips//cert.zip
set PASSWD XYZ

set cmd "wget --header \"Authorization: Bearer $PASSWD\" -O $SRCFILE $SRC"
eval spawn $cmd
```

Problem is the wget command is not working. When I run `wget --header Authorization: Bearer XYZ -O /tmp/cert.zip https://na.artifactory.swg-devops.com/artifactory/generic-local//latest/misc/copy_zips//cert.zip` on my linux command line it works fine. I also tried running the command on expect command line

```
expect1.1> spawn wget --header "Authorization: Bearer XYZ" -O /tmp/cert.zip https://na.artifactory.swg-devops.com/artifactory/generic-local//latest/misc/copy_zips//cert.zip

spawn wget --header Authorization: Bearer XYZ -O /tmp/cert.zip https://na.artifactory.swg-devops.com/artifactory/generic-local//latest/misc/copy_zips//cert.zip
2815
```

And this also works fine.

But this command in expect script won't work. I have tried the following alternatives which do not seem to work:

```
set cmd 'wget --header "Authorization: Bearer $PASSWD" -O $SRCFILE $SRC'

set cmd "wget --header "Authorization: Bearer $PASSWD" -O $SRCFILE $SRC"
```

I am not sure what am I missing with the quotes.

Comment: try `spawn wget --header "Authorization: Bearer $PASSWD" -O $SRCFILE $SRC`

Comment: Define "won't work". What **does** happen? Honestly, "not working" is the worst possible problem description. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the other Asking questions in the Help Center

Answer (score 0):

Put the command in a list and use the expansion operator

```
set cmd [list wget --header "Authorization: Bearer $PASSWD" -O $SRCFILE $SRC]
spawn {*}$cmd
```

Or as @sexpect comments, don't put the command in a variable at all.